# How to search for each keyword from file1 in file2 and return the number of times it was found?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have two text files. A list of keywords in file1 and text in file2. I want to search for each keyword from file1 in file2 and return the number of times it was found?

*File 1*
`kw1`
`kw2`
`kw3`

*File 2*
**`kw1`**`blabla`
**`kw2`**`blablabla`
**`kw1`**`blabla`

The code should print how many times each keyword is found throughout the text file2.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: `"the python code should"`.. where is the python code? Your ***question*** should include an attempt of **your** python code. Provide us with your attempt to perform the task and point out the difficulties you encounter. Otherwise we don't know where you are stuck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well this is simple.
Ill only do it for the First File, but to show how many times it comes up, you can count, but this is a one word per line test.

```
import os

file1 = open("file1.txt", "r") # Make sure you added the keywords in beforehand
file2 = open("file2.txt", "r") #These will open the file ready for use.

step1 = file1.readlines()
step2 = file2.readlines()
pos1 = 0
for line in step1:
    test = line.find('hello')
    print(test)
```

This will print:

```
0
0
0
-1
```

0 being found and -1 being not found with File 1 having the following words put into it.REMEMBER it reads each line seperately, so if you have multiple per line it might not work.

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
Bye
```

Good Luck, Msg me if u have any problems.

Comment: You could add a counter to monitor the 0 output for you.

Comment: 1+ for beating me to this answer. ;)

Comment: Even relatively feeble answers like this only encourage more really low-quality questions like this one to be asked—aren't there enough all ready?. Suggest you refrain in the future.

Comment: @martineau Whilst you might be a pro at coding - some of us are not and need help. And this question is entirely valid.

Comment: @martineau FYI this is a coding website designed for members of the community to help other members. Technically you're right but Im also right in saying that its a coding question, on a coding website, for others in the coding genre to answer. So I overrule your Off-topic - ness